# Keyring.backend error TortoiseHg on Mac

Tags: macos, python, mercurial

I have successfully installed Python keyring and use it with TortoiseHg on Windows but I am having a problem on Mac OS Mojave.

When performing a "push", I get "No handlers could be found for logger 'keyring.backend'".   I did install the Python library and have modified the hgrc file to be as follows,

```
[ui]  
 username = xxx <xxx@xxx.com>

[paths]
#default = https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/scan-namer-and-filer-repository-2
BitBucket = https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/scan-namer-and-filer-repository-2

[tortoisehg]    
fullpath = True

[trusted]    
users = administrator, bcrow
groups = wheel

[extensions]   
mq =
mercurial_keyring =
hgext.mercurial_keyring = /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/hgext/mercurial_keyring.py

[backend]

default-keyring=keyring.backends.OS_X.Keyring (priority: 5)
```

There seems to be little help for Mac OS users.  I don't even know if this is a warning or an error which should cause me concern.

Could someone provide guidance or references?

Responses to comments and answer

1. I added the "mercurial_keyring =" before I discovered that keyring is NOT distributed with the MacOS version of Tortoise HG.  I agree it should be removed.
2. The full text of the error message is "No handlers could be found for logger "keyring.backend" - That's it.  Nothing about passwords.
3. I was not able to put "[backend] in the keyringrc.cfg file because it was not properly created by the Python installation.
4. Fortunately, I found 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192177/how-can-i-get-the-keyring-extension-working-for-mercurial-in-ubuntu-18-04

   which told me how to create the necessary folders and the keyringrc.cfg file on MacOS.

I removed the "[backend]" line from the hgrc file.
**Push still does not work without entering authentication information.**
Don't know where to go from here.

The current version of the hgrc (redacted) is as follows,

[ui]
username = xxx

[paths]
BitBucket = https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/scan-namer-and-filer-repository-2

[tortoisehg]
fullpath = True

[trusted]
users = xxxx, xxxx
groups = wheel

[extensions]
mq =
hgext.mercurial_keyring = /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/hgext/mercurial_keyring.py

Answer (score 0):

1. I see **2** different `mercurial_keyring` extensions in your config, while only one (bundled with THG) is needed
2. This is error, because full text of message is

> No handlers could be found for logger "keyring.backend" Please enter
>   password for encrypted keyring

and without it you'll not get access to stored in your keyring passwords

3. `[backend]` section (with content) have to be a part of keyringrc.cfg in appropriate location, not Mercurial's

Comment: And JFYI https://medium.com/@kaikoenig/python-library-woes-on-ubuntu-18-04-32c6828b5f56 (yes, Ubuntu, but not for OS-specific problem)

Comment: What is the "appropriate location" for keyringrc.cfg?